# Defining a new command for making functional lines / package

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, equations, diagrams

As you have probably guessed from the title my mother tounge is not English. 
Therefore I have no idea if "Functional lines" is the correct term for what I am looking for.

Basically I am looking to make a command similar to the one below

```
\functionalines{3x}{x-4}{F_x = (3x)(x-4)}
```

Then the output should be similar to the tikz code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
negativ/.style={blue,dashed},
positiv/.style={red},
vertlinje/.style={dotted,opacity=.7},
node distance=1.5ex,
nullpunkt/.style={fill=white,inner sep= 1pt}]
  \draw [->,>=stealth] (-5,0) node (linestart) {} -- (5,0) node (lineend) {};
  \node (null1) at (-2,0) [label=above:-2] {};
  \node (null2) at (1,0) [label=above:1] {};
  \node [matrix] (produktledd) [below left=of linestart]{
    \node [left] (f1) {$x+2$}; \\
    \node [left] (f2) {$x-1$}; \\
    \node [left] (f)  {$f(x)= x^2+ x - 2$}; \\
   };
  \draw [vertlinje] (null1)       -- (null1 |- f);
  \draw [vertlinje] (null2)       -- (null2 |- f);
  \draw [positiv]   (null1 |- f1) -- (lineend |- f1);
  \draw [negativ]   (f1)          -- (null1 |- f1) node[nullpunkt] {$0$};
  \draw [negativ]   (null1 |- f)  -- (null2 |- f);
  \draw [positiv]   (null2 |- f2) -- (lineend |- f2);
  \draw [negativ]   (f2)          -- (null2 |- f2) node[nullpunkt] {$0$};
  \draw [positiv]   (f)           -- (null1 |- f)  node[nullpunkt] {$0$}
                (null2 |- f) node[nullpunkt] {$0$} -- (lineend |- f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A very good friend showed me this code =) Although there are a few small edits that would have been nice. 
The top vectorline should be lowered a tad, and go over the equations. Above the equations and the vector there should be an x, indicating we are looking at the x-axis. 
Preferably there should be a line below the equations, same length as the line above. Images below. 
Is this possible to accomplish?

How the code looks

http://www.diskusjon.no/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=461590

If I could get the output any way I want, I would want it to be like the one below.

[image]

So yeah, any idea, how to make a command which gives the desired output?

Comment: So you want to give TeX the factors of a function, have it decide when those factors are positive and negative, and deduce when the product is positive or negative?  I think to do that right would require implementing or embedding a computer algebra system within TeX...

Comment: Ofcourse something simpler. For instance, I would have no problems at all manually typing in where each factor is zero, and wheter it is right or left centered. I thought that was the purpose of this site? To discuss and give solutions to problems, as optimal as possible. And as you say the ideal solution seems impossible, I am therefore interested seeing how close one could get.  For an examplethe polynom package can factor equations. =)

Comment: For start, you may want to look at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-tab and http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tableaux

Comment: Are you sure you want the line to go over the equations? I was a bit confused by this at first, because it makes the diagram look very much like a table, especially with the alignment of the `x` above the equations. Also, am I right in assuming that the first and second equation are swapped in your example pictures?

Comment: @Jake The first and second equation were swapped. (I took the liberty of fixing that, as I wrote the bloody thing in the first place.)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Sorry if I gave the impression it wasn't an interesting problem.  It is.  I was trying to say you might get more, better answers if you refine your question to something more feasible, rather than set the bar so high.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use PGFplots for this. By plotting functions using

```
 \addplot [restrict y to domain=0.5:inf] {(x-2)>0};
```

all coordinates that do not fulfill the condition will be discarded.

I've defined an environment `functionallines` of the form

```
\begin{functionallines}[<pgfplots arguments>]{<zero positions>}{<lower>:<upper>}
```

The `<zero positions>` argument takes a comma-separated list of x-values where any of the functions are zero or not defined. At these positions, a vertical line will be drawn through the function plots, and the positions will be printed in black at the top of the diagram. If you want to change the labels for these positions, use the `<pgfplots arguments>` to supply `extra x tick labels={<first label>,<second label>,...}`.

The optional argument can also be used for things like switching off the regular tick labels by setting `xtick=\empty`, or changing the drawing style of the functions by, for example, setting `negative/.style={orange,dashed}, positive/.style={green, ultra thick}`.

The `<lower>` and `<upper>` arguments define the x-range of the plot.

You can then add new lines using

```
\functionalline[<LaTeX math code>]{<expression>}{<vertical position>}{<list of zeros>}
```

where the optional argument `[<LaTeX math code>]` can be used to specify the code used to print the equation.

If the function evaluates to a nonreal value (divide by zero) at one of the zero positions, an `x` is printed instead of a `0`.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
\begin{functionallines}{-1,1}{-2:2}
    \functionalline{x-1}{1}{1}
    \functionalline{x+1}{2}{-1}
    \functionalline[f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}]{(x-1)/(x+1)}{3.5}{-1,1}
\end{functionallines}
```

[image]

---

```
\begin{functionallines}[
    xtick=\empty,
    negative/.style={orange,dashed},
    positive/.style={green, ultra thick}
    ]{0,90,180,270,360}{-20:380}
    \functionalline[\cos(x)]{cos(x)}{1}{90,270}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x)}{2}{0,180,360}
    \functionalline[\cos(x) \cdot \sin(x)]{cos(x) * sin(x)}{3}{0,90,180,270,360}
\end{functionallines}
```

[image]

---

Setting the labels for precise zero positions using `extra x ticks labels`, specifying the normal ticks using `xtick={<list>}` to avoid overlaps.

```
\begin{functionallines}[
    extra x tick labels={$\sqrt{5}$,$\pi$,$2\pi$},
    xtick={0,1,4,5}]{2.23,3.14,6.3}{0:6.5}
    \functionalline[x-\sqrt{5}]{x-2.23}{1}{2.23}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x*180/3.14)}{2}{3.14,6.28}
    \functionalline[(x-\sqrt{5})\cdot \sin(x)]{(x-2.23)*sin(x*180/3.14)}{3}{2.23,3.14,6.28}
\end{functionallines}
```

[image]

---

And here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    shift down/.style={
         y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*(#1)}}
    },
    shift down/.default=1,
    every axis plot post/.style={restrict y to domain=0.5:inf},
    positive/.style={
        no markers,
        red
    },
    negative/.style={
        no markers,
        blue
    },
    /tikz/function label/.style={
        anchor=east
    },
    step functionallinenumber/.code={
        \stepcounter{functionallinenumber}
    },
    title entries/.initial={}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\functionalline[4][\@empty]{
    \edef\plots{
        \noexpand\addplot [negative, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2<0};
        \noexpand\addplot [positive, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2>0};
    }
    \plots
    \node at (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#3) [function label] {%
        \ifx#1\@empty%
            $#2$%
        \else%
            $#1$%
        \fi
    };

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {#4} {
       \node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt,
        declare function={x=##1;} % Set 'x' to current position
    ] {%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% Use the fpu library, because it doesn't throw an error for divide by zero, but sets result to +/- inf
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{0}{\hspace{-0.75ex}0}{x}% Check whether result is zero. The \hspace is necessary because of a bug in the fpu library. (Update 11 June 2012: Doesn't seem to be the case anymore, the \hspace can be removed)
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    };
    }   
}

\newenvironment{functionallines}[3][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[        
        extra x ticks = {#2},
        grid=none,
        xticklabel pos=right,
        hide y axis,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        every tick label/.style={
            anchor=base,
            yshift=1ex,
            gray!50
        },
        every extra x tick/.style={
            every tick label/.style={
                anchor=base,
                yshift=1ex,
                inner xsep=0pt,
                fill=white,
                text=black
            }
        },
        extra x tick style={grid=major},
        xtick pos=right,
        major tick length=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.75},
        domain=#3,
        samples=100,
        y dir=reverse, y = -0.5cm,
        clip=false,
        #1
    ]
}{
    \coordinate (bottom right) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
    \coordinate (top right) at (rel axis cs:1,1);
    \end{axis}
    \draw [-latex] (top right-|current bounding box.west) -- (top right) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw (bottom right) -- (bottom right-|current bounding box.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{functionallines}{-1,1}{-2:2}
    \functionalline{x-1}{1}{1}
    \functionalline{x+1}{2}{-1}
    \functionalline[f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}]{(x-1)/(x+1)}{3.5}{-1,1}
\end{functionallines}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{functionallines}[xtick=\empty]{0,90,180,270,360}{-20:380}
    \functionalline[\cos(x)]{cos(x)}{1}{90,270}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x)}{2}{0,180,360}
    \functionalline[\cos(x) \cdot \sin(x)]{cos(x) * sin(x)}{3}{0,90,180,270,360}
\end{functionallines}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{functionallines}[
    extra x tick labels={$\sqrt{5}$,$\pi$,$2\pi$},
    xtick={0,1,4,5}]{2.23,3.14,6.3}{0:6.5}
    \functionalline[x-\sqrt{5}]{x-2.23}{1}{2.23}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x*180/3.14)}{2}{3.14,6.28}
    \functionalline[(x-\sqrt{5})\cdot \sin(x)]{(x-2.23)*sin(x*180/3.14)}{3}{2.23,3.14,6.28}
\end{functionallines}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! There is a problem though, if the zero value is smaller than -3 or larger than 3 then the `xmin`/`xmax` and `domain` has to be redefined.

Comment: @TorbjornT.: You're right, that could become a problem. I've added an optional argument for specifying the range.

Comment: Kinda new at this place, So hopefuly I will not get butchered for asking this. Why are there many numbers other than zeros in the first code, compared to the second one? I guess it has something to do with the code, but I could not see it. Secondly this must be by far, the best post I have seen so far. Really helped, me you are a saint. Now, hopefully I am allowed to ask this here: Would it be possible to swap the lines? From positive to negative. like 1-x. And how would one go about replacing 0 with x. For example (1-x)/(1+x). -1 should be x. To line should be opposite. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: No problem, follow-up questions are very welcome. For your first question: Are you asking why the numbers from -3 to 3 appear at the top of the diagrams produced with the first code, while with the second code you only get those numbers where the function evaluates to zero? For your second question: Sure, you can use `\functionalline{1-x}{1}{-1}`, or `\functionalline{1+x}{1}{-1}`. My solution uses the `pgfmath` engine, which is described starting on p. 527 of the [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), which is quite flexible.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: ...and to change the `0` symbols to `x`, just change the line `\node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [fill=white, inner sep=1pt] {0};` to `\node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [fill=white, inner sep=1pt] {x};`.

Comment: @Jake I think you misunderstood him slightly, he doesn't want _all_ `0`s changed to `x`, only those where the function would become undefined. E.g. in `f =  (1-x)/(1+x)`, if `x=-1` one divides by zero. Hence for that line there should be an `x`, but for the `(1-x)` line, there should be `0`. Easy enough for the first two lines, you could just have an extra argument in `functionallines` for the node text, but a little more complicated when there are more than one node in a line, with (possibly) different node texts. Perhaps you've got a good way of doing that, I know I haven't ...

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've added a bit of code that checks whether the function really evaluates to zero, and if it doesn't (such as when we divide by zero) an `x` is printed.

Comment: @Jake I almost feel bad for bothering you more with this, but I noticed that if you load `amsmath` the example with sine and cosine breaks, you get the following error:
`! Use of \\functionalline doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.97 ...functionalline[\cos(x)]{cos(x)}{1}{90,270}` 

I guess `amsmath` redefines `\sin` and `\cos`, and that this redefinition somehow conflicts with `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Jake Addendum: Having `\sqrt{x}` in the optional argument (without `amsmath`) produces the same error, while `\frac` works.

Comment: @TorbjornT.: You're right, it was an expansion issue (it always is...). Should work now.

Comment: Awesome job jake. Now for a closing comment. What if I want exact values in the top row? For an example the line x - \sqrt 5. Should have a 0 at about 2.23, and display in the top 
1 2 sqrt 5 3 4 5
So the ability for picking exact values would be great. A minimal example below
[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/CC0oS.png[/IMG]
Seems like I am never happy right ? ^^ Well not it works 90% so I am very glad.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Like that? Don't hesitate to ask for adjustments - we've come this far, might as well do it properly. I would be interested in knowing what this is for, if you don't mind me asking. Are you a maths teacher?

Comment: I actually sat here laughing for 5 minutes jake. I think i laughed over how amazing this is.considering I thought it would be impossible. You are the best. Alas I am not a math teacher, yet. Going to be that in 4 years though. Then all the hand outs will be made in latex. Currently I am writing solutions for old, and new exams. I try to do all the math exams for students in the age 16-18. Here is the current look =)
http://www.2shared.com/document/oSp0f5gr/R2_online.html

So yeah, would it not be simpler to just remove some of the overlapping characters instead of making two overlaping lines?

Comment: To revive this answer a bit: if the complete code is used now, I've noticed that the vertical space for the \dfrac{}-display fraction is not correct, in addition to the fact that the lines are in *reverse* order. Any clues as to what has changed with the packages, @Jake?

Answer (score 2):

Change `\functionallines` to the following (five input arguments) to input list of points for undefined function. Just an extension of Jake's code.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\functionalline[5][\@empty]{
    \ifx#1\@empty
        \edef\equation{#2}
    \else
        \edef\equation{#1}
    \fi
    \edef\plots{
        \noexpand\addplot [negative, shift down=#3] {#2<0};
        \noexpand\addplot [positive, shift down=#3] {#2>0};
        \noexpand\node at (axis cs:\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#3)     [function label] {$\equation$};
    }
    \plots
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {#4} {
        \node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [fill=white, inner sep=1pt] {0};
    }   
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {#5} {
        \node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [fill=white, inner sep=1pt] {x};
    }   
}
```