# Second Derivative

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

I would like to make a function analysis and I'm trying to make a tabular which includes the first and second derivatives and the curve arrow which indicates the monotonicity of my function and I can't make the curve arrows which connects the monotonicity of the first derivative and the second. The best I can do is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $f'(x)$ /1.5, $f''(x)$ /2,$f(x)$/2.5}{$-\infty$, $0$ ,$1$ , $2$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,+,z,- ,d,-,z,+}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,-,t ,- ,d,+,t ,+}%
\tkzTabVar%
{ -/  ,  +/ ,-D+/  /  ,  -/  ,+/  /  }%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Although I try to manage something like this

[image: wanted]

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Hi! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please make a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Sorry my doc is in french. There is a chapter n0 11 in the doc page 57  You have some explanations about how to use some special coordinates and to draw your personal tools. I can help you but I need to see an example. Do you have a link to show what you want exactly or perhaps you can add a picture ?

Comment: related: [Function sign table, complete with first and second derivative, plus concavity/convexity and asymptotic behaviour - a better way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38862)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help in putting curved arrows in place:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{arrow style/.style = {blue,->,> = latex',
shorten > = 6pt,
shorten < = 6pt}}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $f'(x)$ /1.5, $f''(x)$ /2,$f(x)$/2.5}{$-\infty$, $0$ ,$1$ , $2$ , $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,+,z,- ,d,-,z,+}%
\tkzTabLine{ ,-,t ,- ,d,+,t ,+}%
% \tkzTabVar%
% {  -/  ,  +/ ,-D+/  /  ,  -/  ,+/  /  }%
\pgfnodebox{i1}[virtual]{\pgfxy(2.5,-5)}{$+\infty$}{0pt}{0pt}
\pgfnodebox{n1}[virtual]{\pgfxy(4.5,-5.5)}{$11$}{0pt}{0pt}
\pgfnodebox{n2}[virtual]{\pgfxy(6.5,-6)}{$-5$}{0pt}{0pt}
\pgfnodebox{n3}[virtual]{\pgfxy(8.5,-6.5)}{$-16$}{0pt}{0pt}
\pgfnodebox{i2}[virtual]{\pgfxy(10.5,-5)}{$+\infty$}{0pt}{0pt}
\pgfsetendarrow{\pgfarrowtriangle{4pt}}
\pgfnodeconncurve{i1}{n1}{-65}{-180}{.5cm}{.5cm}
\pgfnodeconncurve{n1}{n2}{0}{110}{.5cm}{.5cm}
\pgfnodeconncurve{n2}{n3}{-80}{-180}{.5cm}{.5cm}
\pgfnodeconncurve{n3}{i2}{0}{-90}{1.5cm}{1cm}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way of producing the same kind of output:

[image: Curved arrows]

Comment: Thank you for your time but the curved arrows have to go up or down like the image's..

Comment: It's fine but I think it's preferable in this case to use tikz's syntax and not pgf's syntax because it's not easy for new user of the package. Then you placed the values by hand and the tkz-tab gives coordinates to help the user. But It's a solution !

Comment: @AlainMatthes I agree. I think your solution is much better. I don't understand French so I was lost with the `tkz-tab` package and couldn't figure out how to use its coordinates. (I still don't understand looking at your code how this is done, I'm afraid.) You are probably right about the syntax, too. I just find `tikz` even more difficult than `pgf` but no doubt this is because when I first did it, the former was not an option (or not one of which I was aware). I just really put this out there to provide an idea. I'm happy to see you've provided a more satisfactory solution!

Answer (score 22):

I modify my answer to get what you want ...

My answer is not complete because I need more time ...

My package is useful for french mathematics teachers. We never make tables like you want. Below I made the "traditional" table ...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab,tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
    \tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]{$x$/1,$f’(x)$/2,$f’'(x)$/2,$f(x)$/4} 
 {$-\infty$,$0$,$2$,$3$,$+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,-, ,-,0,+, }%
\tkzTabLine{,+,0,-,0,+, ,+, }%
\tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$ ,R/ ,R/ ,-/-16,+/ $+\infty$ } % french method

\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=4,xstep=1,
        ymin=-16,ymax=16,ystep=8]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=red,samples=100,domain = -1:4]{\x**4-4*\x**3+11}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the french method, it's usual to place some intermediate values like 11, -5 or -16

If you want to personalize the result you can use the `help` option. With this option you get

[image]

Now you have all the nodes defined in the picture. With this coordinates you can place what you want.

Now you can use N13 , N14 etc. to place the nodes and to draw some curve arrows. I can post a complete answer tomorrow but perhaps you can find the solution ...

**Final**

Now we know the nodes necessary for placing the curved arrows. We can place the values like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]{$x$/1,$f’(x)$/2,$f’'(x)$/2,$f(x)$/4} {$-\infty$,$0$,$2$,$3$,$+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,-, ,-,0,+, }%
\tkzTabLine{,+,0,-,0,+, ,+, }%
\node [below] at (N13){\scriptsize$+\infty$};
\node [below=1cm] at (N23){\scriptsize$11$};
\node [below=2cm] at (N33){\scriptsize$-5$};
\node [above] at (N44){\scriptsize$-16$};
\node [below] at (N53){\scriptsize$+\infty$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Th next step is to draw arrows ... It's easy and there are several possibilities. We can give a name to the last nodes and ...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$/1,$f’(x)$/2,$f’'(x)$/2,$f(x)$/4} {$-\infty$,$0$,$2$,$3$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,-, ,-,0,+, }
\tkzTabLine{,+,0,-,0,+, ,+, }

\node [below] (n1) at (N13){\scriptsize$+\infty$};
\node [below=1cm](n2) at (N23){\scriptsize$11$};
\node [below=2cm] (n3) at (N33){\scriptsize$-5$};
\node [above] (n4) at (N44){\scriptsize$-16$};
\node [below] (n5) at (N53){\scriptsize$+\infty$};

\draw[>->] (n1) to [out=-90,in=180] (n2);
\draw[>->] (n2) to [out=0,in=90] (n3);
\draw[>->] (n3) to  [out=-90,in=180] (n4);
\draw[>->] (n4) to [out=0,in=-90] (n5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Final remarks: I used `kz-fct` to draw the 2D plot but you can make this step independently. There iis no link finally with your question. You can draw this curve only with tikz or with the good tool PGFPlots. A lot of guys here can help you for this. `tkz-fct` needs to install gnuplot and sometimes it's not easy.

Comment: I would appreciate to see your complete answer because i don't know how it works the hole thing. I will use your example as a guide for other examples of mine. Thank you!

Comment: @Giannis Now it's complete. The only problem is my solution is not automatic. It's possible but it's a big work

Comment: I make copy paste this part of code and it shows me error...

Comment: Can you describe the error ? You try with the last code ? (it's preferable to avoid tkz-fct )

Comment: Sorry I made a mix with my source and the code for adding the picture. I modify the answer

Comment: It is very hard and difficult procedure to set up a table like this...It takes time and the results are not what i expected. Do you know any other program to make tables like this? Thank you for your time anyway! I really apreciate your effort!

Comment: @Giannis No program or package, I think. The reason is you want something no usual or "academic". You can find some packages like tkz-tab but for the final drawing with curve arrows I think you need to program with pstricks or tikz.

Comment: @Giannis I understand your point about it taking time but I'm not clear about what you expected. Alain Matthes's solution looks very much like the diagram you wanted (to my untrained eye, at least). What isn't right about it?

Comment: @cfr The result of this program is sufficient but tha ratio effort result is huge. Too much effort for something simple. I want to make tables like the one i posted within a few minutes and not hours. So i am asking if you know a program for this purpose. To make my function analysis and to complete the table of the 1st 2nd derivative and the curved arrow sooner than latex does.

Comment: Mr. Matthes I think you should write a book, a concise introduction to Latex to math teachers (in french) including the fundamentals, tkzeuclid for geometry, tkz-fct and tkz-tab for studying functions, maybe some packages for lines planes and solid geometry and for statistics. That will be great. Most teachers I know only use MS Word. Reading a general latex book won't help much except for writing some text with eqs. Hope you'll do it someday; I benefited a lot from your tkzeuclide and will be the first to buy such book and recommend it. Best regards.

Comment: @Paracosmiste Thanks ! I have just gone through a (long) hard time with my health. I resume the programming slowly but I encounter a lot of difficulties with the various updates. For the book, I do not believe that it is possible ... and especially I can not promise anything anymore

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using PSTricks drawings inside a table. (Compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` og `xelatex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  tableposition = top,
  labelformat = empty % Removes ``Table'' or ``Figure'' from caption.
]{caption}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Increasing function.
\newcommand*\increase{
  \raisebox{-1.2ex}{%
    \begin{pspicture}(0.5,0.5)
      \psline[linecolor = blue]{->}(0,0)(0.5,0.5)
    \end{pspicture}%
  }
}

% Decreasing function.
\newcommand*\decrease{
  \raisebox{-1.2ex}{%
    \begin{pspicture}(0.5,0.5)
      \psline[linecolor = blue]{->}(0,0.5)(0.5,0)
    \end{pspicture}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \caption{Monotony of a function~$f$.}
  \label{tbl:1}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
    \toprule
     $x$      & $-\infty$ &           & $0$ &           & $1$ &           & $2$ &           & $+\infty$ \\
    \midrule
     $f'(x)$  &           & $+$       &     & $-$       &     & $-$       &     & $+$       &           \\
     $f''(x)$ &           & $-$       &     & $-$       &     & $+$       &     & $+$       &           \\
     $f(x)$   &           & \increase &     & \decrease &     & \decrease &     & \increase &           \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Note:** I know it's not exactly what you asked for but I like this solution, so please consider it as my suggestion of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but as you said it is not what i ask for. I write a math book for students and i want to be specific at some symbols. Do you know how can i sent inbox at specific person here in this forum?

Comment: You can use a users name, like @Giannis, in a comment to notify him. For more in depth conversations please use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to know tikz, there is a tikz dedicated package: `tkz-tab`. Documentation in french, which maybe a drawback, but if you take a look at this [on-screen doc](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-tab/doc/tkz-tab-screen.pdf), with many examples, you will see it is quite complete, and the results are close to perfection.

Answer (score 2):

This is modified version of @AlainMatthes, the `tkz-tab` package author, with the help of `tikz` options. The result is close enough to the original picture.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[t style/.style={solid}]

\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$/.5,$f'(x)$/.5,$f''(x)$/.5,$f(x)$/3} {$-\infty$,$0$,$2$,$3$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,-,t,-,0,+, }
\tkzTabLine{,+,0,-,0,+,t,+, }

\node [below] (n1) at (N13){$+\infty$};
\node [below=1cm](n2) at (N23){$11$};
\node [below=2cm] (n3) at ([yshift=1em]N33){$-5$};
\node [above] (n4) at ([yshift=1em]N44){$-16$};
\node [below] (n5) at (N53){$+\infty$};

\node[below=1ex]at(n2){$ \mathrm{\Sigma.K.} $};
\node[below=1ex]at([xshift=.5ex]n3){$ \mathrm{\Sigma.K.} $};
\node[below=1ex]at([xshift=1ex]n4){$ \mathrm{T.E.} $};

\draw[>->] (n1) to [out=-90,in=180] (n2);
\draw[>->] (n2) to [out=0,in=90] (n3.west);
\draw[>->] (n3.east) to  [out=-90,in=180] (n4);
\draw[>->] (n4) to [out=0,in=-90] (n5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TikZ is enough to draw simple tables and plots.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!20}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.2,yscale=.8]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,-7.5)
(1,0)--+(-90:7.5)
(0,-1)--+(0:10) 
(0,-2)--+(0:10) 
(0,-3)--+(0:10)
(5.5,-1)--+(-90:1) (7.5,-2)--+(-90:1);
\end{scope}
\path
(0,0) node{$x$} (0,-1) node{$f'(x)$} 
(0,-2) node{$f''(x)$} (0,-4.5) node{$f(x)$}
(1,0) node{$-\infty$}
(5,0) node{$2$}
(7,0) node{$3$}
(9,0) node{$+\infty$}
(1,-3) node (A) {$+\infty$}
(3,-4) node (B) {$11$} +(-90:.5) node{$\Sigma$.K.}
(5,-5) node (C) {$-5$} +(-90:.5) node{$\Sigma$.K.}
(7,-6) node (D) {$-16$} +(-90:.5) node{T.E.}
(9,-3) node (E) {$+\infty$};
\foreach \p in {(3,0),(3,-1),(3,-2),(5,-2),(7,-1)} 
\path \p node{$0$};
\foreach \p in {(2,-1),(4,-1),(6,-1),(4,-2)} 
\path \p node{$-$};
\foreach \p in {(2,-2),(6,-2),(8,-2),(8,-1)} 
\path \p node{$+$};

\begin{scope}[>-latex,thick,blue]
\draw (A) to[out=-60,in=180] (B);
\draw (B) to[out=0,in=120] (C.north west);
\draw (C.south east) to[out=-60,in=180] (D);
\draw (D) to[out=0,in=-90] (E);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.2]
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-18)--(0,16) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[dashed] (2,0)|-(0,-5) (3,0)|-(0,-16);
\draw[blue,thick] 
(-1,15).. controls +(-85:.5) and +(180:.8) ..
(0,11) .. controls +(0:1.2) and +(95:1) ..
(2,-5) .. controls +(-85:1) and +(180:.5) ..
(3,-16) .. controls +(0:.5) and +(-92:1) ..
(4,0) .. controls +(88:.5) and +(-92:1) ..
(4.5,14);
\path
(0,11) node[above right]{$11$}
(0,0) node[below left]{O}
(2,0) node[above]{$2$} 
(3,0) node[above]{$3$}
(0,-5) node[left]{$-5$}
(0,-16) node[left]{$-16$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking for curved arrows, check out the

```
\lcurvearrowne
\lcurvearrowse
\lcurvearrownw
\lcurvearrowsw
```

of the package MnSymbol

Comment: I tried these symbols but the result wasn't what i expected. The main problem is to combine the upper tikz package with the curve arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I could get with `xypic` so far, maybe I will improve it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-7pt/\dir{>}}
\begin{equation*}\xymatrix@R=5mm{
        +\infty \ar@{ >->}@(d,l)[dr] & & & & +\infty\\
        & 11 \save[]+<0mm,-10pt>*\txt{$\Sigma$.K.}\restore \ar@{ >->}@(r,u)[dr]+L & & & \\
    & & -5 \save[]+<0mm,-10pt>*\txt{$\Sigma$.K.}\restore \ar@{ >->}@(d,l)c+R;[dr]-R & & \\
    & & & -16 \save[]+<0mm,-10pt>*\txt{T.E.}\restore \ar@{ >->}@(r,d)[uuur] &
}\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: first example output]