# Why does \pgfsetendarrow (now) have no effect?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm not sure whether I am blind to the obvious or whether this is a bug or perhaps an intended deprecation.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{16cm}{9cm}
        \pgfnodebox{a}[stroke]{\pgfxy(10,8)}{A}{3pt}{3pt}
        \pgfnodebox{b}[stroke]{\pgfxy(10,6.5)}{B}{3pt}{3pt}
        \pgfsetendarrow{\pgfarrowtriangle{4pt}}
            \pgfnodeconnline{a}{b}
    \end{pgfpicture}

\end{document}
```

As far as I can tell, a few weeks ago, this would have produced two boxes containing 'A' and 'B' with a vertical arrow pointing down connecting them. However, here's the output I get from my MWE now:

[image: Arrowless arrow]

Indeed, code which I produced PDF from a few weeks ago now produces an arrowless version of a diagram made using this method. Moreover, the code I posted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162412/39222) now produces an arrowless version of the diagram included there.

Am I missing something? Or has something changed which I'm not aware of?

Note that I am aware that this may work fine using `tikz` syntax [untested] but I have a number of diagrams which I originally prepared using `pgf` syntax and I would prefer to stick to that if possible. So if `\pgfsetendarrow` is deprecated, I'd prefer a drop-in replacement if at all possible which will work with my existing diagrams.

Note that I don't get errors or even warnings about this when I compile. Nothing to say the command is undefined or similar. It just seems to be ineffective.

Comment: did you update PGF to v3.00

Comment: Apparently I did. I just checked and the Changelog is for 3.0.0 so I must have picked it up last time I ran `tlmgr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the TikZ 2.10 manual, after documenting on page 616

```
\pgfsetarrowsend{⟨start arrow kind⟩}
```

it is stated:

> Warning: If the compatibility mode is active (which is the default),
>   there also exist old commands called `\pgfsetstartarrow` and
>   `\pgfsetendarrow`, which are incompatible with the meta-arrow
>   management.

The TikZ 3.0.0 manual does not cite anymore this; it only documents:

```
\pgfsetarrowsend{⟨end arrow tip specification⟩}
```

on page 1017. I would assume this compatibility mode is now inactive by default.

Hence, if you updated the package, you may want to switch to the new version. Indeed:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{16cm}{9cm}
        \pgfnodebox{a}[stroke]{\pgfxy(10,8)}{A}{3pt}{3pt}
        \pgfnodebox{b}[stroke]{\pgfxy(10,6.5)}{B}{3pt}{3pt}
        \pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[scale=1.5pt]} % with arrows.meta or
        % \pgfsetarrowsend{stealth}
            \pgfnodeconnline{a}{b} 
 \end{pgfpicture}

\end{document}
```

is perfectly working.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I would never have found that. I tried searching the manual for `\pgfsetendarrow` but that obviously returned nothing. The moment at which old code stops working seems an odd one to choose for removing mention from the documentation, especially since no warning is issued during compilation. Presumably, the command is still somehow recognised as defined even though it does nothing? That's rather odd. Anyway, thanks very much for this solution.

Comment: `\pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[scale=1.5pt]}` seems to be roughly equivalent to the code I was using. Perhaps you could add this to your answer for completeness? (Just in case somebody wants to know. This isn't terribly important.)

Comment: @cfr: you're welcome. Sure, tomorrow I'll edit the answer with your suggestion (on this laptop I don't have the version 3.0.0 installed).