# Typing of math sign charts

Tags: math-mode, context

For typing of quantities of solving mathematical problems I would like to type *signs charts* (diagrams to visualize the values of expressions). Something like this:

```
x-5       -    |    -    |    +
x+4       -    |    +    |    +
---------------o---------@------------
          +   -4    -    5    +
```

(@ means full circle). Primarily seeking solutions in ConTeXt, but for inspiration welcome and solutions in Plain or LaTeX. Maybe someone has something similar to what would suit my needs? I do not want to insert a picture, I am rather interested in solutions in a tables.

Thanx Jaroslav

Comment: Just draw it using `tikz` that is the easiest method

Comment: Take a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/function-sign-table-complete-with-first-and-second-derivative-plus-concavity-c

Comment: @MaartenDhondt Your link points to LaTeX solutions which doesn't work in ConTeXt, IMHO.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Defining a new command for making functional lines / package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30588)

Comment: Review this question for several detailed option http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/function-sign-table-complete-with-first-and-second-derivative-plus-concavity-c

Comment: I am thinking of a way automate this. What is the rationale for using solid vs open circles?

Comment: Full circle means that the zero point is part of the domain of expression, while the empty circle means that the zero point is not in the domain (zero point of denominator etc).

Comment: The linked question (38862) doesn't have vertical lines in the answers, so the difficulty of lining up the -4 and 5 goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the macro `\sgchart` which generates desired table. The usage is:

```
\sgchart {list of points} {formula: signs, formula: signs, formula: signs etc}
```

for example

```
\sgchart {-4, ~5} {x-5: --+, x+4: -++, (x+4)/(x-5): +-+}
```

If the point value isn't preceded by `~` then it is printed with solid bullet (default) and if the `~` precedes then circle is printed. The number of points and the number of formulas are unlimited.

The macro works in plain TeX (and in LaTeX too, because the basic plain TeX syntax is used in this macro). ConTeXt sets catcode of the `&` to 12 and this brings a little problem. We need to set this catcode to 4 in the area where the macros are defined. This is the reason why there are two lines with `\ecatcode` macro here. When these lines are used then the macro works in ConTeXt too.

```
\newdimen\tcolw \tcolw=2.5em % the column width
\edef\ecatcode{\catcode`&=\the\catcode`&\relax}\catcode`&=4
\def\sgchart#1#2{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil##\quad&##\hfil\crcr\sgchartA#2,:,%
   \omit\sgchartR&\kern.2pt\sgchartS{.5\tcolw}\relax\sgchartE#1,\relax,%
   \sgchartS{.5\tcolw}\relax\cr
   \noalign{\kern2pt}&\def~{}\kern.5\tcolw\sgchartD#1,\relax,\cr}}}
\def\sgchartA#1:#2,{\cr\ifx,#1,\else $#1$&\sgchartB#2{}\expandafter\sgchartA\fi}
\def\sgchartB#1{\hbox to\tcolw{\hss$#1$\hss}\sgchartC}
\def\sgchartC#1{\ifx,#1,\else
   \strut\vrule\kern-.4pt\hbox to\tcolw{\hss$#1$\hss}\expandafter\sgchartC\fi}
\def\sgchartD#1#2,{\ifx\relax#1\else\hbox to\tcolw{\hss$#1#2$\hss}\expandafter\sgchartD\fi}
\def\sgchartE#1#2,{\ifx\relax#1\else
    \ifx~#1\sgchartS\tcolw\circ \else\sgchartS\tcolw\bullet\fi \expandafter\sgchartE\fi}
\def\sgchartR{\leaders\vrule height2.8pt depth-2.4pt\hfil}
\def\sgchartS#1#2{\hbox to#1{\kern-.2pt\sgchartR \ifx\relax#2\else
   \kern-.7pt$#2$\kern-.7pt\sgchartR\fi\kern-.2pt}}
\ecatcode

\sgchart{-4, ~5} {x-5: --+, x+4: -++, (x+4)/(x-5): +-+}

\bye
```

[image: sgchart]

Comment: Does anybody know why ConTeXt sets catcode of `&` to 12? This means that it is incompatible with plain TeX.

Comment: [My thoughts](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/some-thoughts-on-lowering-the-learning-curve-for-using-tex-part-i/) on why changing the catcode of `&` is a good idea.

Comment: I asked for it in ConTeXt mailing list. The answer is that context table mechanisms don't use & (and never used it) so there is no reason to make & special. The _ and ^ are also normal characters. For now developers keep the $ for math (and in math mode the & ^ _ work as expected).

Answer (score 2):

Is this enough?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
x-5     -   |   -   |   +
x+4     -   |   +   |   +
------------0-------@----------
        +  -4   -   5   +
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

If not you could use the (mathematical) `array` environment.

Comment: O,sorry, there should be some linebreakes in the code.

Comment: You have to leave a blank line before the code. If you select the code parts and click the `{}` icon, the blank line is automatically supplied and the code is properly indented by four spaces (hitting Control-K does the same).

Answer (score 2):

Plain TeX (requires e-TeX, though):

```
\def\crulefill{\leaders\hrule
  height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
  depth -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt\relax
  \hfill
}
\def\hollow{$\kern-.8pt\circ\kern-.8pt$}
\def\filled{$\kern-.8pt\bullet\kern-.8pt$}

$$
\vbox{\offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
  \halign{%
    \strut$#$\hfil\quad&
    \hfil\qquad$#$\qquad\hfil&
    \hfil\vrule#\hfil&
    \hfil\qquad$#$\qquad\hfil&
    \hfil\vrule#\hfil&
    \hfil\qquad$#$\qquad\hfil\cr
  x-5&-&&-&&+\cr
  x+4&-&&+&&+\cr
  \multispan{2}\crulefill&\omit\hfil\hollow\hfil&
    \omit\crulefill&\omit\hfil\filled\hfil&\omit\crulefill\cr
  &+&\omit\hidewidth$-4$\hidewidth&-&\omit\hidewidth$5$\hidewidth&-\cr
}}
$$

\bye
```

[image]