# Line graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a diagram which looks like this in TikZ:

[image]

This is similar to other sign diagrams (ie. [Typing of math sign charts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230273/typing-of-math-sign-charts)), but I do not want to label signs, just to section off the intervals $[-N+1,N-1], [N+1, 3N-1]$  with the square brackets.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
alr/.style = {draw=red!50, line width=2pt, semitransparent, 
              {Bracket[reversed,line join=miter,scale=0.8]}-{Bracket[reversed,line join=miter,scale=0.8]}
              },
 ar/.style ={-Straight Narb}
                        ]
\draw (-5mm,0) -- ++ (9,0);
\foreach \i [count=\x  from 0] in {-N, 0, N, 2N, 3N}
    \draw (2*\x,1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm) node[below] {$\i$};
%
\draw[alr] ( 1mm,0) -- (39mm,0);
\draw[alr] (41mm,0) -- (79mm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you.