# Monotony table and signs

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[color, colorT = red!30, colorC = yellow!20,colorL        =             blue!20,  colorV = lightgray!20, espcl=4]{$x$ /1,$f''(x)$ /1, $f'(x)$ /2,   $f(x)$ /2 }
  {$-\infty$ ,$0$, $+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine {,+ , z,+ ,  }
\tkzTabVar[color=red]{-/  $-\infty$,R/ /,+/ $+\infty$ /}%
\tkzTabVal[draw]{1}{3}{0.5}{}{$0$}
\tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -/$f(0)=0$/, +/ $+\infty$ / }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following shape:

[image]

I want , however, to add one last thing in the table. In the box of the derivative of f, that shows its monotony I would like to add the sign of the derivative. That is , add a plus sing at the right in the center below the arrow and a minus sign at the left in the center above the arrow.

How can I do that?

Comment: Look at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-tab/tkz-tab-screen.pdf and  http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tablor/tablor.pdf.  This question may be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/function-sign-table-complete-with-first-and-second-derivative-plus-concavity-c/38875#38875

Comment: @R.Schumacher I did look at altermundus... but there does not exist a similar table! Besides most of the monotony tables I create in tikz I base them on altermundus.

Comment: As for the link you suggest , no, it is not similar. That link explains how to create a monotony table with concavity or convexity but not how to add plus or minus signs near the arrow of monotony..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add these two lines after `\tkzTabVal` in your code:

```
\tkzTabVal{1}{3}{.25}{}{$-$}
\tkzTabVal{1}{3}{.75}{}{$+$}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.