# How can I create a mathematical sign chart?

Tags: math-mode, charts

I've done some Googling and haven't found any way to create the below image in latex:

[image]

The derivative isn't important; it's the line with the `+`, `0` below it including the `-1` and `2`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I don't know how to do this within LaTeX itself, but I often use PowerPoint to make simple diagrams, then use the add-on IguanaTeX (http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) to add LaTeX symbols/ equations etc, then save it as jpg/png and insert into my LaTeX document. It's crude but very easy to do.

Comment: Needless to say, you could do this with tikz.  The easiest solution would by to put the +++0---0+++ as text in a node at try to fit the line to it.

Comment: Is [Defining a new command for making functional lines / package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30588) useful?

Comment: Where is the `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using a plain TeX alignment and `cleaders`...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\tabskip0pt\openup 3pt
\vbox{\halign{#&&\hbox to 1.2in{\cleaders\hbox{#}\hfill}&\hbox to 0pt{\hss$#$\hss}\cr
&\multispan6 \hfil $f(x) = 6(x-2)(x+1)$ \hfil \cr
\noalign{\medskip}
$f'(x)$ & + & 0 & $ - $ & 0 & + \cr
&---&\vert&---&\vert&---&\cr
&&-1&&2\cr}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create such diagrams using TeX primitives. The `\diag` macro is defined here with the syntax:

```
\diag { f'(x) ; 4*+ ; -1 ; 3*- ; 2 ; 4*+ } 
%      label  ; 4cm of plus ; point -1 ; 3cm of minus ; point 2 ; 4cm of plus
```

The number of pairs "point ; space amount of plus/minus" are unlimited.

```
\def\diag#1 {\par\def\diagL{}\moveright2em\vbox\bgroup \hbox\bgroup \diagA #1 ;;}
\def\diagA#1;{\llap{$#1$}\diagB}
\def\diagB#1*#2;#3;{\dimen0=#1cm \advance\dimen0 by-.6em 
   \kern.3em \xleaders\hbox{$#2$}\hskip\dimen0
   \kern.3em
   \ifx;#3;%
      \egroup \medskip \hrule \kern-5pt
      \hbox{\diagL}\egroup 
   \else
      \xdef\diagL{\diagL 
         \kern#1cm \vrule height22pt depth-12pt \hbox to0pt{\hss$#3$\hss}}%
      \hbox to0pt{\hss$0$\hss}%
      \expandafter \diagB
   \fi
}

\diag { f'(x) ; 4*+ ; -1 ; 3*- ; 2 ; 4*+ } 

\bye
```