# Reproduce sign of a function diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-tab

I need to reproduce the sign of a function graph down below. How would I do that? Is there any package I can use to recreate that?

[image: Sign of a function diagram]

Comment: Related I suppose: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/defining-a-new-command-for-making-functional-lines-package

Answer (score 3):

To display variation of functions you could use package `tkz-tab`. 
See below a MWE. I suggest you take look at [Visuel_Tikz_0.6](http://gte.univ-littoral.fr/sections/stage-latex/visual-tikz/downloadFile/file/Visuel_Tikz_0.50.pdf?nocache=1384195529.55) in section "23 Les Tableaux de variation".

```
\documentclass[english]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 , $f'(x)$ /1.2} { $-\infty$ , -4, 4 , 10 , $+\infty$ }
    \tkzTabVar{-/1 , +DH/3 , +/5 , -C/3, +D/8}
    \tkzTabLine{ t,+, d ,h ,d,-,z,+ }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]