# How to create a sign line for functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a tikz picture like the one included below.
Can you help me with the code?
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can see at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334236/reproduce-sign-of-a-function-diagram/334241.

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30629/586

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, the package `tkz-tab` can be used:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[espcl = 1.2]{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 1 , $g(x)$ / 1 , $h(x)$ / 1}{$-\infty$, $-2$, $-1$, $-3/4$, $2/3$, $3$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, , , -, , , z, , +, , z, -,}
   \tkzTabLine{, -, z, +, z, , -, , z, , +, , }
   \tkzTabLine{, +, d, -, d, +, z, -, d, +, z, -}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the previous piece of code, one obtains

[image: Sign line for functions]