# Functional lines bug

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, packages, diagrams

In an old question the user Jake, helped me make some code to create "function

[Defining a new command for making functional lines / package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/defining-a-new-command-for-making-functional-lines-package)

The code and result is amazing, alas per 2019 this code exhibits some annoying bugs. As an example the code

```
\begin{functionallines}{-1,1}{-2:2}
    \functionalline{x-1}{1}{1}
    \functionalline{x+1}{2}{-1}
    \functionalline[f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}]{(x-1)/(x+1)}{3.5}{-1,1}
\end{functionallines}
```

Produces

[image]

While the actual output should look like

[image]

**Problems**

- The labels are slightly shifted to the right
- The order of the functions is reversed
- Some spacing problems with the height of the `dfrac` command and the numberline.

I have tried to study the code in detail, but alas fixing these issues is beyond my abalities at the moment. Any help fixing these minor bugs in this amazing code is much appreciated.

Code #

(Directly takes from Jake's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    shift down/.style={
         y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*(#1)}}
    },
    shift down/.default=1,
    every axis plot post/.style={restrict y to domain=0.5:inf},
    positive/.style={
        no markers,
        red
    },
    negative/.style={
        no markers,
        blue
    },
    /tikz/function label/.style={
        anchor=east
    },
    step functionallinenumber/.code={
        \stepcounter{functionallinenumber}
    },
    title entries/.initial={}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\functionalline[4][\@empty]{
    \edef\plots{
        \noexpand\addplot [negative, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2<0};
        \noexpand\addplot [positive, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2>0};
    }
    \plots
    \node at (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#3) [function label] {%
        \ifx#1\@empty%
            $#2$%
        \else%
            $#1$%
        \fi
    };

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {#4} {
       \node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt,
        declare function={x=##1;} % Set 'x' to current position
    ] {%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% Use the fpu library, because it doesn't throw an error for divide by zero, but sets result to +/- inf
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{0}{\hspace{-0.75ex}0}{x}% Check whether result is zero. The \hspace is necessary because of a bug in the fpu library. (Update 11 June 2012: Doesn't seem to be the case anymore, the \hspace can be removed)
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    };
    }   
}

\newenvironment{functionallines}[3][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[        
        extra x ticks = {#2},
        grid=none,
        xticklabel pos=right,
        hide y axis,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        every tick label/.style={
            anchor=base,
            yshift=1ex,
            gray!50
        },
        every extra x tick/.style={
            every tick label/.style={
                anchor=base,
                yshift=1ex,
                inner xsep=0pt,
                fill=white,
                text=black
            }
        },
        extra x tick style={grid=major},
        xtick pos=right,
        major tick length=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.75},
        domain=#3,
        samples=100,
        y dir=reverse, y = -0.5cm,
        clip=false,
        #1
    ]
}{
    \coordinate (bottom right) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
    \coordinate (top right) at (rel axis cs:1,1);
    \end{axis}
    \draw [-latex] (top right-|current bounding box.west) -- (top right) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw (bottom right) -- (bottom right-|current bounding box.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{functionallines}{-1,1}{-2:2}
    \functionalline{x-1}{1}{1}
    \functionalline{x+1}{2}{-1}
    \functionalline[f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}]{(x-1)/(x+1)}{3.5}{-1,1}
\end{functionallines}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{functionallines}[xtick=\empty]{0,90,180,270,360}{-20:380}
    \functionalline[\cos(x)]{cos(x)}{1}{90,270}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x)}{2}{0,180,360}
    \functionalline[\cos(x) \cdot \sin(x)]{cos(x) * sin(x)}{3}{0,90,180,270,360}
\end{functionallines}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{functionallines}[
    extra x tick labels={$\sqrt{5}$,$\pi$,$2\pi$},
    xtick={0,1,4,5}]{2.23,3.14,6.3}{0:6.5}
    \functionalline[x-\sqrt{5}]{x-2.23}{1}{2.23}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x*180/3.14)}{2}{3.14,6.28}
    \functionalline[(x-\sqrt{5})\cdot \sin(x)]{(x-2.23)*sin(x*180/3.14)}{3}{2.23,3.14,6.28}
\end{functionallines}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more fiddling I was able to fix the problems

- **Correction 1:** Removed `y dir=reverse`.
- **Correction 2:** From the line

  ```
  \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{0}{\hspace{-0.75ex}0}{x}%
  ```

  I removed `\hspace{-0.75ex}` as noted in the comments.

I still need to figure out how give the `dfrac` a bit more space

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    shift down/.style={
         y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*(#1)}}
    },
    shift down/.default=1,
    every axis plot post/.style={restrict y to domain=0.5:inf},
    positive/.style={
        no markers,
        red
    },
    negative/.style={
        no markers,
        blue
    },
    /tikz/function label/.style={
        anchor=east
    },
    step functionallinenumber/.code={
        \stepcounter{functionallinenumber}
    },
    title entries/.initial={}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\functionalline[4][\@empty]{
    \edef\plots{
        \noexpand\addplot [negative, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2<0};
        \noexpand\addplot [positive, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2>0};
    }
    \plots
    \node at (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#3) [function label] {%
        \ifx#1\@empty%
            $#2$%
        \else%
            $#1$%
        \fi
    };

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {#4} {
       \node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt,
        declare function={x=##1;} % Set 'x' to current position
    ] {%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% Use the fpu library, because it doesn't throw an error for divide by zero, but sets result to +/- inf
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{0}{0}{x}% Check whether result is zero. The \hspace is necessary because of a bug in the fpu library. (Update 11 June 2012: Doesn't seem to be the case anymore, the \hspace can be removed)
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    };
    }   
}

\newenvironment{functionallines}[3][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[        
        extra x ticks = {#2},
        grid=none,
        xticklabel pos=right,
        hide y axis,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        every tick label/.style={
            anchor=base,
            yshift=1ex,
            gray!50
        },
        every extra x tick/.style={
            every tick label/.style={
                anchor=base,
                yshift=1ex,
                inner xsep=0pt,
                fill=white,
                text=black
            }
        },
        extra x tick style={grid=major},
        xtick pos=right,
        major tick length=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.75},
        domain=#3,
        samples=100,
        y = -0.5cm,
        clip=false,
        #1
    ]
}{
    \coordinate (bottom right) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
    \coordinate (top right) at (rel axis cs:1,1);
    \end{axis}
    \draw [-latex] (top right-|current bounding box.west) -- (top right) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw (bottom right) -- (bottom right-|current bounding box.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{functionallines}{-1,1}{-2:2}
    \functionalline{x-1}{1}{1}
    \functionalline{x+1}{2}{-1}
    \functionalline[f(x) = \dfrac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}]{(x-1)/(x+1)}{3.5}{-1,1}
\end{functionallines}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{functionallines}[xtick=\empty]{0,90,180,270,360}{-20:380}
    \functionalline[\cos(x)]{cos(x)}{1}{90,270}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x)}{2}{0,180,360}
    \functionalline[\cos(x) \cdot \sin(x)]{cos(x) * sin(x)}{3}{0,90,180,270,360}
\end{functionallines}

\hspace{1cm}

\begin{functionallines}[
    extra x tick labels={$\sqrt{5}$,$\pi$,$2\pi$},
    xtick={0,1,4,5}]{2.23,3.14,6.3}{0:6.5}
    \functionalline[x-\sqrt{5}]{x-2.23}{1}{2.23}
    \functionalline[\sin(x)]{sin(x*180/3.14)}{2}{3.14,6.28}
    \functionalline[(x-\sqrt{5})\cdot \sin(x)]{(x-2.23)*sin(x*180/3.14)}{3}{2.23,3.14,6.28}
\end{functionallines}

\end{document}
```