# Functional lines part II

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sorry for the barrage of questions, however I still run into some problems with the code for creating the functional lines. I was able to fix some minor bugs here [Functional lines bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499762/functional-lines-bug). However, the code still does not produce the results I expect

Take the following code as an example

```
    \begin{functionallines}[
    extra x tick labels={$\mathrm{e}^{-3/2}$},
    xtick={-0.5,0,1}]{0.223}{-0.5:1}
        \functionalline[f(x)=2\ln(x)+3]{2*ln(x)+3}{2}{0.223}
        \functionalline[]{1}{3}{}
    \end{functionallines}
```

The result looks like this

[image]

However, I would have expected the result instead to look like this:

[image]

I would suspect the mismatch is because the function is not defined for values `< 0` and so it is not drawn. Is there a way to fix this to properly display logarithms?

In the image above the `x` means that the function is undefined at that particular point, while an `0` means that the function has a zero there.

I wonder why this is displayed incorrectly in the first image? In particular for `x = e^{-3/2}` I would have expected to see a `0` as the function is zero here, and for `x = 0` I would have expected to see a `x`.

## Problems:

- Is there a better way to toggle between where a function is zero and where it is undefined. Manually or automatic. (Maybe a optional argument to insert x markers into the lines?)
- Is there a way to show functions in a larger domain than where they are defined?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{
    shift down/.style={
         y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*(#1)}}
    },
    shift down/.default=1,
    every axis plot post/.style={restrict y to domain=0.5:inf},
    positive/.style={
        no markers,
        red
    },
    negative/.style={
        no markers,
        blue
    },
    /tikz/function label/.style={
        anchor=east
    },
    step functionallinenumber/.code={
        \stepcounter{functionallinenumber}
    },
    title entries/.initial={}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\functionalline[4][\@empty]{
    \edef\plots{
        \noexpand\addplot [negative, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2<0};
        \noexpand\addplot [positive, shift down=#3, forget plot] {#2>0};
    }
    \plots
    \node at (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#3) [function label] {%
        \ifx#1\@empty%
            $#2$%
        \else%
            $#1$%
        \fi
    };

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {#4} {
       \node at (axis cs:##1,#3) [
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt,
        declare function={x=##1;} % Set 'x' to current position
    ] {%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% Use the fpu library, because it doesn't throw an error for divide by zero, but sets result to +/- inf
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{0}{0}{x}% Check whether result is zero. The \hspace is necessary because of a bug in the fpu library. (Update 11 June 2012: Doesn't seem to be the case anymore, the \hspace can be removed)
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    };
    }   
}

\newenvironment{functionallines}[3][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[        
        extra x ticks = {#2},
        grid=none,
        xticklabel pos=right,
        hide y axis,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        every tick label/.style={
            anchor=base,
            yshift=1ex,
            gray!50
        },
        every extra x tick/.style={
            every tick label/.style={
                anchor=base,
                yshift=1ex,
                inner xsep=0pt,
                fill=white,
                text=black
            }
        },
        extra x tick style={grid=major},
        xtick pos=right,
        major tick length=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.75},
        domain=#3,
        samples=100,
        y = -0.5cm,
        clip=false,
        #1
    ]
}{
    \coordinate (bottom right) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
    \coordinate (top right) at (rel axis cs:1,1);
    \end{axis}
    \draw [-latex] (top right-|current bounding box.west) -- (top right) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw (bottom right) -- (bottom right-|current bounding box.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{functionallines}[
        extra x tick labels={$\mathrm{e}^{-3/2}$},
        xtick={-0.5,0,1}]{0.223}{-0.5:1}
            \functionalline[f(x)=2\ln(x)+3]{2*ln(x)+3}{2}{0.223}
        \end{functionallines}
    \end{center}

\hspace{1cm}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{functionallines}[
        extra x tick labels={$e^{-1/2}$},
        xtick={-1,0,1}]{0.606}{-1:1.5}]
            \functionalline{x}{1}{0}
            \functionalline[2\ln+1]{2*ln(x)+1}{2}{0.6065}
            \functionalline[f'(x) = x(2 \ln x + 1)]{2*x*ln(x)+x}{3.5}{0,0.6065}
        \end{functionallines}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am wondering what you mean by "Is there a way to fix this to properly display logarithms?". As you say, the logarithm is not defined for negative arguments. How would you like to define it? `log(abs(x))`?

Comment: I just want to hide it for `x<0`, nothing fancy. 

I also noticed `f(x) = x ln(x)` also gives a `0` for `x = 0`. While it is true that `f → 0` as `x → 0`, because `f(0)` is undefined the command should display an `x` for `x = 0`.

Comment: Yes, this is not a computer algebra system. Please have a look at `pgfmathparser.code.tex` and the other files in that directory (it is `.../tex/generic/pgf/math/` where `...` depends on your TeX installation) how these functions are implemented. For instance, `ln` is defined in `pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex`, and as you see it is defined as ` A+(B+(C+(D+(E+F*x)*x)*x)*x)*x` with some constants `A`, `B` etc. Jake's answer is magic, but still limited by the fact that TeX is not a modern computer algebra system.

Comment: I am fine manually defining where the function should exists =)

Comment: You can do this with `ifthenelse`. The problem is that if you define the function differently for one point, and the samples do not hit this point, you won't see it. But yes, you can do sth like `\functionalline[f(x)=2\ln(x)+3]{ifthenelse(x>0,2*ln(x)+3,-inf)}{2}{0.223}`.

Comment: @marmot This still displays the function for negative values. Is there a way to hide it completely?